# How to recreate buttons in previous activity?

Tags: java, android, recreate

I have a problem with code in Android Studio.

I have `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`.

In `ActivityA` I have buttons. `ActivityB` is about settings. For example, I can choose the theme of the app. All done using `SharedPreferences`.

If I change theme to DARK with this code:

```
Button Settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
Settings.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);     
Settings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shapestylethis3);
```

and I press back to go o `ActivityA` - then buttons are changed.

Now when I'm in `ActivityB` and I wanna change back for theme `LIGHT` then I would like to get back this default button on `ActivityA`:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
```

But I don't know how to achieve that. `ActivityB` is changing right after clicking the button "save" because apart from saving to `SharedPreferences` I used also `recreate();` in `onClick`.

But when I put `recreate()` in the `onResume` in `ActivityA`, then it's like an infinite loop. I will be really thankful for helping me finding a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily avoid the `recrate()` going in the infinite loop in your `ActivityA` using a `public static` variable or a `SharedPreference` (any of these two you might prefer).

Let us have a `public static` variable in `ActivityA` like the following.

```
public static boolean shouldRecreate = false;
```

Now when you are changing the style from `ActivityB`, set the `ActivityA.shouldRecreate = true` and do not call the `recreate()`.

Now in the `onResume` function of your `ActivityA` check the value of `shouldRecreate` and call the `recreate()` function accordingly.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (shouldRecreate) {
        recreate();
        shouldRecreate = false;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad to know that I could help you! Welcome to StackOverflow!